# How can I use Ambient Occlusion as bump map?

Tags: ambient-occlusion

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:[Blender Quick Tips #1 - ambient occlusion node](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUS0P6l3d2s)
I tried to go a bit deeper, and add bump to the greeny areas using the ambient occlusion node, but it didn't work.

[image]

Why won't the ambient occlusion work with the bump node? I meant to use it like Kaizen's tutorial here (at the end of the tutorial he uses the output of the AO map I believe):
[How to Create Professional Materials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-x-b2U-MSgc)

Adding a noise texture didn't work either, please see the picture below:

[image]

How can I use the Ambient Occlusion map as bump?

Comment: The AO use the real topology, it needs bumps and cavities to work. Also if you use Eevee you need to activate the option in the Render panel.

Comment: Blender's bump mapping is only actually run at a particular point in the shading pathway, regardless of how nodes are wired.  AO depends on normal (note the input) while any bump mapping nodes are calculated *before* this.  You can't do it live, but you could bake AO and use that bake as bump.  This is one of those things that's kind of borderline-bug in Blender; I suspect that it was implemented that way to work right for bump-mapped displacement output, which is a weird thing that breaks noodle order, but which is convenient for users.